How can I make a Power BI semantic model not demand the presence of a data gateway to get data from the web?
I created a Power BI report that collects data from:

a MySQL database (located on the external server)
a webpage (currency exchange rate table)

When everything worked fine on the Power BI Desktop, I published a semantic model and report on My workspace and tried to refresh it. Refreshes fail!
The failure was the "unavailability of the data gateway (personal mode)". That was correct, as the data gateway (personal mode) was not running on my laptop. But note! Both data sources are from the cloud! So, no data gateway is necessary.
I experimented. I removed the connection to a web page and left only the MySQL connection — no problem! When I reintroduced a connection to a webpage, a semantic model expected data gateway again.
For a test, I installed the data gateway (personal mode), and when it runs, the semantic model refreshes. However, I do not want to keep my laptop running whenever a refresh is expected.
How can I make the semantic model not demand the presence of an unnecessary data gateway?
The setting page of the semantic model looks like this:


Have a look at this, check you connection settings, are you using web.contents?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72235312/power-bi-do-i-need-a-gateway-connection-when-importing-data-from-a-web-page

Yes, I checked that. Results are the same as the author of the post had described: _switching from Web.BrowserContents to Web.Contents doesn't work. _

Finally, I managed to get rid of the annoying problem.
The problem was that the working folder in which I had saved *.pbix files locally (before publishing them to the Power BI service) was synchronized with the OneDrive cloud. This most likely creates a conflict with the Power BI automatic update mechanism.
I did the following:

Opened a "faulty" report on my local machine with Power BI Desktop
I Saved it as... again in a local folder, which is not backed by OneDrive!!! Cloud synchronization mechanism
Published it then to My workspace
And it start to work, without complaining on lack of data gateway!


Check the authentication in your report when you connect.  Are you connecting to the website and the web SQL server with anonymous?

Thanks, @Phil, for looking at it.
I assigned credentials within the semantic model settings for a MySQL database and set Anonymous authentication for the website. The webpage does not ask for a signup.
